# Call (or send event) erlang function from C app/library

Tags: c, erlang

I have an application and library that interacts with low-level hardware protocols. Now I'm writing an erlang application for fast parsing of data and send it to distributed databases. However, I'm a newbie at erlang and I've stuck at simple thing: what is the efficient way to connect C library(or application) with erlang and how to notify erlang that another block of data is ready for processing (e.g. how to call erlang function from C library or trigger an event)? Time is important here, and what shall I use -- simple ports, driver ports or NIFs? Or there are better ways for solving my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an option, you can run your C application as hidden erlang node using erl_interface lib. http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/ei_users_guide.html#id56593 . And send messages to real erlang node  http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/ei_users_guide.html#id60866, or use rpc - remote proc calls to perform http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/ei_users_guide.html#id57714

Answer (score 1):

You should try simple port first sending events to stdout. If the bandwidth of such implementation is enough, you have the benefit of erlang vm be safe from  crashes of your application. If you need more then using port driver is an option, that interface was developed exactly for such purposes.